# Discord.py rewrite, Setting up background tasks, background tasks not loading

Tags: python-3.x, background-task, discord.py

I can't seem to figure out how to activate my background tasks run time.  It's supposed to change the colour of a role which is does successfully if I make the code run after an event.  But setting it up to work in the background keeps failing.  No errors either, my guess is the task never loads.

```py
#Login and bot initializer
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(f"Username:  {client.user.name}")
    print(f"User ID:  {client.user.id}")
    print('---------------------------------')


#Runtime Background Tasks
async def runtime_background_task():
    id=client.get_guild(564683412699480094)
    colours = [discord.Colour(0xe91e63),discord.Colour(0x0000FF0),discord.Colour(0x00FF00),discord.Colour(0xFF0000)]

    print("BACKGROUND TASK>> Functional")

    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        i = random.randint(0, len(colours))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        for role in id.roles:
            if role.name == 'bot':
                await role.edit(server=id, role=role, colour=colours[i])
                break
```

Comment: Colour changing bots have been banned to avoid flooding the API, in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) extension to make this easier on yourself.  Here we have a task that runs every second to change the color of a role.

I didn't see where you have `id` defined, so I'm using a `before_loop` to initialize the server from an id:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.tasks import loop
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from random import choice

bot = Bot("!")

colours = [discord.Colour(0xe91e63), discord.Colour(0x0000FF0), discord.Colour(0x00FF00), discord.Colour(0xFF0000)]

guild_id = 12345
role_name = "bot"
role_to_change = None

@loop(seconds=1)
async def colour_change():
    await role_to_change.edit(colour=choice(colours))
    print("Task")

@colour_change.before_loop
async def colour_change_before():
    global role_to_change
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    role_to_change = get(guild.roles, name=role_name)

colour_change.start()
bot.run("token")
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext.tasks'  Also I added the ID to the code so it's easier to understand ;)

Comment: You might need to update your discord.py version: `pip install -U discord.py`

Comment: The update fixed that but the code doesn't seem to do the task either.  No errors but doesn't actually do anything either.

Comment: @KA I was missing the `colour_change.start()` line

Comment: I added the code in like this but it's till not working
https://pastebin.com/x8MH7ZFN

Comment: You're passing a `Guild` object, not an id, to `get_guild` in the before loop.